# what happens with this formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

apparently $|x|+|y|=1$ determines a set of lines each of which goes into infinity and which intersect in such a way that they create a rectangle...but why do we say that they define a rectangle when in fact they only intersect that way and define infinitely many other points....? it's no like they actually stop when they reach the intersection of each other....?

Comment: $|x|+|y|=1$ is NOT a set of lines.  It is a square.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the set of all points $(x,y)$ such that $|x|+|y|=1$.

Clearly, points where $|x|>1$ cannot be in the set. Similarly for $y$.

So this set must be bounded within the region with $|x|\leq 1$ and $|y|\leq 1$. How could this "go to infinity"?